# Trouble deploying Node.js app to heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I have tested and completed a version of my app that uses Node.js and more specifically it incorporates the node twitter module. When following Heroku's deployment guide and I execute `heroku git:clone -a groupmetweetbot` I get the following output in the console: [image]

If I continue on and execute the following:
`$ cd groupmetweetbot`
`$ git add .`
`$ git commit -am "make it better"`
`$ git push heroku master`

the console tells me that the app is deployed.

This leaves me with a few questions. How can I fic this filename too long issue? I can't find any easy answer on how to start and sleep my app on Heroku. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you're hitting this bug https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3697

you could try using npm v3

Comment: That answer in that issue thread seems unclear. Are you suggesting just switching to npm v3 would resolve the issue? Also can't find a good way to change to v3 if that is the solution

Comment: yes, because your issue is that windows doesn't support the long file paths that v2 uses

Comment: Following the link you sent I'm still having trouble figuring out what v3 even is and how to upgrade to it. It seems like the issue I'm having is common yet there is no good solution. Any ideas?